# Starting Windows Driver Development

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2012, driver, minifilter

I am planning to start developing windows drivers and I have some questions.

- How can I start a simple Visual Studio driver project? I am using Visual Studio Ultimate 2012 and I have read on MSDN how to make a simple software driver, but in the tutorial, in the `New Project` window, there are more options than I have. To be more precise, I don't have `Templates > Visual C++ > Windows Drivers`. Or If i am searching online for `User Mode Driver (UMDF)`, I can't find nothing. I have installed WDK 8.1
- What additional changings should I do in order to build correctly a driver project?

Comment: WDK support is integrated with recent versions of VS (2012 & 2013). You should be seeing those options, assuming you've installed both correctly.

Comment: How is possible to install them wrong? :) I dont think that's the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe WDK 8.1 may not work with Visual Studio 2012.  I did confirm that you can install WDK 8 on top of Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate, and the project templates will show up.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/hardware/ff557573

Answer (score 1):

VS2012 does not work with WDK 8.1.
You need WDK 8.0

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms247116%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

```
To restore the default project templates
In the command prompt, navigate to the location of devenv.exe. This file is located in <Visual Studio Installation Path>\Common7\IDE.
NoteNote

If you are running Windows Vista or Windows 7, you must open the command prompt as an administrator by right-clicking the command prompt and then clicking Run as administrator.

Type "devenv /installvstemplates" and press Enter.
```